# from dream.simulation.Queue import Queue No module named 'CoreObject'

Tags: python

Can't even get started with this. Using the import statements from section 2 (pp5) of the ManPy documentation module,i.e.

```
from dream.simulation.Queue  import Queue
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-4053c10305c7>", line 1, in <module>
    from dream.simulation.Queue  import Queue

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dream-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/dream/simulation/Queue.py", line 30, in <module>
    from CoreObject import CoreObject

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CoreObject'
```

I am using Python 3.8.10 in the Sypder3 IDE on Linux Mint-20.02.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your import statement to

```
from dream.simulation.imports import Queue
```